# Where (or how) should I define the schema in a select statement when using PostgreSQL?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, schema, npgsql

I have an application built upon ASP.NET 3.5 and PostgreSQL 8.3.  My database has 3 users, a data owner (xxx-owner), a data editor (xxx-editor), and a data viewer (xxx-viewer).  Each user has their own schema called xxx-schema, xxx-editor-schema and xxx-viewer-schema. All the data is stored in xxx-schema.

This requires that I specify the schema when connecting to the database as either the xxx-editor or xxx-viewer users as shown in the following snippet.

```
NpgsqlCommand pgCommand = new NpgsqlCommand();
pgCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT 
                        bldg_id,
                        bldg_name,
                        bldg_no,
                        FROM " + this.schema + @".buildings
                        WHERE UPPER(bldg_id) LIKE UPPER(@id);";

pgCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", "%" + id + "%");
pgCommand.Connection = pgConnection;
```

If I were to follow this route I would specify the schema in the Web.config. However, there must be a better way to specify which schema should be used. I would like to be able to remove the string concatenation entirely if possible.

What is the best way to define the schema to be used in the SQL statement?

---

*EDIT*

The following from the [PostgreSQL User Manual](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) looks promising.

> SearchPath - Changes search path to specified and public schemas.

From my limited testing it works alright in my situation.  However, this is a PostgreSQL only solution. Is there perhaps a more database agnostic solution, do most databases provided such functionality?

---

*EDIT 2*

I've marked the answer below which lead me to changing the schema lookup order at the database level.  With the following change I do not need to add code in my SQL statements.

```
ALTER USER xxx-viewer SET search_path TO '$user', xxx, public, sde
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the schema search path on a per-session basis using:

```
SET search_path TO myschema
```

If you want to fall back to the public schema, you could use:

```
SET search_path TO myschema, public
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Additionally, I permanently modified the search_path for each user via "ALTER USER xxx-viewer SET search_path TO '$user', xxx, public, sde" This way I don't need additional code in my SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do:

SET SCHEMA 'myschema';

This statement is the same that `SET search_path TO myschema, public` but more