# Should the schema always be explicitly defined in the SQL statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

Earlier I had asked the question:

[Where (or how) should I define the schema in a select statement when using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651527/where-or-how-should-i-define-the-schema-in-a-select-statement-when-using-postgr)

The answer I accepted was to modify the search_path for the connecting user so that the schema need not be specified in the SQL. However, now I wonder if I should always specify the schema in SQL rather than allow the schema to be automatically inferred by the search path. This seems like it would be a safer approach and would be more portable to other databases.

This question is different than the previous one in that I want to know what the best practices are for defining the schema in SQL, rather than how it can be done.

Should the schema always be explicitly defined in the SQL statement?

** Note: I would not hard code the schema name but would allow it to be configurable through the Web.config file so that the schema could change from one installation to another. **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to hardcode schema into `SQL` statements.

You should keep it in the application settings and issue `SET search_path` after connecting to the database.

If your application is used by multiple users with their own schemas, your life will be much easier if you don't hardcode schema name into `SQL`.

In other words,

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("schema") + ".table";
```

is a bad way;

```
SQLCommand("SET search_path = " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("schema"), connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
string query = "SELECT * FROM table";
```

is a good way.

Comment: I should probably clarify.  I would not actually hard code the schema but would instead allow it to be configurable via a Web.config setting.  In this case would it more suitable to include the schema in the SQL?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why one is recommended over the other? I know that in the second example the search_path is set only for that session but I am not clear as to why this is an advantage over the first example.

Comment: It's easier to write; it's easier to debug; it's easier to store the queries themselves as the resources; you don't have to append the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("schema") to each table in a join.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! Makes sense to me, especially being able to store the queries as resources. I had not thought of that. Additionally, npgsql allows me to set the search_path in the connection string, removing even more code clutter. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's see - in the DB of the app I maintain there are around a dozen schemas. What would be the order if I put them in "search_path"? And would I put in the schema names (not the tables name and not the fully-qualified table names) in the configuration?

As you have guessed by now I do not use "search_path". But maybe you could store the fully-qualified table names in the configuration in case you ever change you mind about the names of the schemas or the tables themselves.